# Tiny speakers, used in headphones - what are these called?

Tags: audio, identification, speakers

After having searched Mouser and a general search for "tiny speaker", "small speaker", "headphone speaker", and not having found what I am looking for, wanted to see if someone here can help me find the correct term, part-number of the tiny speakers used in headphones (s.a. handsfree kit for mobile phones, mp3 players etc.)

If required I can crack open one of the several damaged handsfree sets and share a pic, but just being lazy.

Edit:
Please note that I am looking for the tiny speaker, as a component - that is housed inside the ear-plugs, head-sets etc., not the whole finished product.

Also, I am looking for speakers that have a diaphragm that vibrates with enough power to push airwaves through an air-tube for a short distance, like 5-6 inches, yet be small enough, light enough to be put behind a lapel pin.

Comment: "Speaker, headphone"?

Comment: "headphone driver"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added:

For components try searching for "speaker" and sort by size.

In Digikey's catalog "speaker" will [get you this](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/cat/audio-products/speakers/720966?k=speaker) and after you reject the expensive tiny specialist units you get eg.

[These](http://www.puiaudio.com/pdf/AS01308MR-R.pdf)

Drawing low on dimensions.
 A few [here](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/AS01308MR-R/AS01308MR-R-ND/1745506)
  Allegedly 13mm x 2mm.

http://www.puiaudio.com/pdf/AS01308MR-R.pdf

---

Or [these - prices](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/PSR-11N08S-JQ/458-1119-ND/2071435)  and [datasheet](http://www.mallory-sonalert.com/Articles/TechAppGuides/Miniature%20Speaker%20Models.pdf).

From 13 mm dia

[image]

http://www.mallory-sonalert.com/Articles/TechAppGuides/Miniature%20Speaker%20Models.pdf
  http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/PSR-11N08S-JQ/458-1119-ND/2071435

---

Earpiece.
 Magnetic earpiece (some)(mot common)
 Piezeoelectric earpiece (some)

Many but not all of these will be relevant, with links - via [Magnetic earpiece](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=magnetic+earpiece&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=I80GT_a1JoWjiAf488CVCQ&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CB8Q_AUoAQ&biw=1599&bih=925)

[image]

and [Piezoelectric earpiece](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=magnetic+earpiece&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=I80GT_a1JoWjiAf488CVCQ&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CB8Q_AUoAQ&biw=1599&bih=925#hl=en&safe=off&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=%22piezoelectric++earpiece%22&oq=%22piezoelectric++earpiece%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=212819l217453l0l217878l14l14l0l1l0l7l442l4241l2-4.8.1l13l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=395db3aa4472f391&biw=2764&bih=1599)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Russell. My question wasn't clear enough, so I've edited it. Actually, these all seem to be the finished products. I am looking for the speakers (sold like other electronic components), that are used to make such products.

Comment: Perfect. Just the thing I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the "element" itself, try a search for "acoustic speaker element" or similar.

This link might give you a list of suitable manufacturers...

http://www.alibaba.com/manufacturers/acoustic-speaker-element-manufacturer.html

I have also seen them referred to as "microspeakers" or "mini-speakers" or mini or micro-speaker elements. As to the "part number" that will depend on the size, type and most importantly the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a headphone "transducer". That or "speaker capsule".